# Blocking Port 1935 in either Router or Firewall

Tags: port, block

I need to troubleshoot an issue by trying to block port 1935 connections to remote servers for a home computer. Note, 1935 is the default port for Flash Media Server's RTMP protocol. My home router is a Netgear one. I followed their instructions by creating a 'Service' in which port 1935 was 'always blocked' and then added that service to the 'Outgoing' part of the Firewall Rules of the router. But my testing still shows a successful connection from a Flash client to port 1935.

I thought there might be some way in the Windows 7 firewall but don't see any?
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Firewall Rules page for the router?

Comment: here it is: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxaCdcZpiglQQ0ZPbERzS0pPWFE

Comment: Are you trying to prevent someone from *outside* your network connecting to a computer inside your network on port 1935, or are you trying to prevent any computers in your home network from connecting to, say, example.com:1935?

Comment: It's the latter one: Trying to prevent computers from my home network to connect to services running on port 1935. Netgear instructions should have worked as I have them configured. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the router and computer?

Comment: Not tried those--am connected to the computer via Remote Desktop and so that will break. Is it worth trying that? Usually, router changes are effective without restarting the computer.

Comment: Ok. Just rebooted the router--that should disconnect the router from the internet, and give the computer a new internet access. If that doesn't work then restart the computer.

Comment: Interesting finding. The port block may be working except, somehow, the Flash application shows connection successfully as rtmp, which would mean 1935. Router's log says: Firewall: packet drop. 192.168.1.14(49927) --> xxx. xxx.xxxx.xxx(1935), Protocol TCP.

Comment: ** Never mind** The port is being blocked correctly, as per my screen cap above. I was confused because the Flash application still said rtmp and so I thought that 1935 was not blocked. But port 1935 was blocked; it was probably rtmp through port 443. Hopefully this will help someone one day. ***

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the router. Many firewall changes don't take effect until the router is rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is what I already said in my Comment to @Matt and as per my screen cap:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxaCdcZpiglQQ0ZPbERzS0pPWFE

I had the settings right in the router: Port 1935 was indeed blocked. However, my test Flash application still reported rtmp, which made me think it was still port 1935. It was actually rtmp over port 443, as I later found out.

So if someone wants to block certain remote ports in a Netgear router then they can follow the steps I took: Create a 'Service' with the desired port; then add that Service to the Firewall Rules 'Outgoing' part, per my screen cap.
Thank you, Matt, for your help!